# Convert XML response to .CSV file

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, csv

I have the following code,

I am sending an array of data to a web service, the response from the web service gets displayed currently in a web form as shown below.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ASent;
        int CSent;
        webservice.Results returned = convert();
        txtResult.Text = System.Convert.ToString(returned.status);
        txtMoreRes1.Text = returned.errorDetails[0].errorDetails;
        txtMoreRes2.Text = returned.errorDetails[1].errorDetails;
        txtMoreRes3.Text = returned.errorDetails[2].errorDetails;
        txtMoreRes4.Text = returned.errorDetails[3].errorDetails;
        date.Text = System.Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today);
        time.Text = System.Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
                }
```

What I now need is for the results 'returned' to be converted from an xml response into a .csv file. Then have the code save that .csv to a location on the C drive. How can I change my code to do this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Not every XML can be converted to CSV

Comment: Umm..Which web service.. your question doesn't make sense, are you referring to some other question then please add a link to it..

Comment: I didnt think that would be nessecary as this form displays the returned response, all I need to do is get the returned response not to load into a web form but just get turned into a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 StringBuilder SbCSV = new StringBuilder();
            int ActualSent;
            int CommitmentSent;
            webservice.summaryResults returned = convert(out ActualSent, out CommitmentSent);
            //txtResult.Text = System.Convert.ToString(returned.status);
            SbCSV.Append(System.Convert.ToString(returned.status));
            //txtMoreRes1.Text = returned.errorDetails[0].errorDetails;
            SbCSV.Append("," + returned.errorDetails[0].errorDetails);
            //txtMoreRes2.Text = returned.errorDetails[1].errorDetails;
            SbCSV.Append("," + returned.errorDetails[1].errorDetails);
            // Similary ...
            txtMoreRes3.Text = returned.errorDetails[2].errorDetails;
            txtMoreRes4.Text = returned.errorDetails[3].errorDetails;
            actualSum.Text = System.Convert.ToString(returned.actualSum);
            commitmentSum.Text = System.Convert.ToString(returned.commitmentSum);
            date.Text = System.Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today);
            time.Text = System.Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
            actualsumsent.Text = ActualSent.ToString();
            commitmentsumsent.Text = CommitmentSent.ToString();
            errorposition1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(returned.errorDetails[0].errorPosition);
            errorposition2.Text = System.Convert.ToString(returned.errorDetails[1].errorPosition);
            errorposition3.Text = System.Convert.ToString(returned.errorDetails[2].errorPosition);
            errorposition4.Text = System.Convert.ToString(returned.errorDetails[3].errorPosition);

            TextWriter Tw = new StreamWriter("Your_FilePath_Name.csv");
            Tw.Write(SbCSV.ToString());
            Tw.Close();
            Tw.Dispose();
```

Comment: i will give it a bash @Pratik and will 'tick' if I canget it to work thanks for input!

Comment: the only thing is this seems not to work and I cant quite work out why, I have called the app a form and I think it is still trying to load up as a form therefore this code is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) to do this stuff.
You must create a class named MyClass with attributes that match your .csv format (each column = one attribute)
you build a List of such class objects and convert to csv this way using FileHelper :

```
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(MyClass));

MyClass[] res = null; //Fill your array here from your code.

// To Write Use:
engine.WriteFile("FileOut.txt", res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with an [XML Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_transformation_language).